# "Add [name] to fillable property to allow mass assignment on [Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User]."

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, mass-assignment

User.php code,
here, whether I use fillable or gaurded, I get the same error.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     *@var array
     */
    // protected $fillable = [
    //     'name',
    //     'email', 
    //     'password',
    // ];
    
    protected $guarded = [];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

UserController.php code,
here, I have tried the mass assignment

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;




class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $data = [
            'name' => 'elon',
            'email' => 'elon@gmail.com',
            'password' => 'password',
        ];

        User::create($data);

        $user = User::all();
        return $user;
    }
}
```

Comment: uncomment the fillable codes on **User** model

Answer (score 10):

You seem to not be importing the user class from the right namespace in your UserController.php

You are using

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User;
```

Use

```
use App\Models\User;
```

instead.

Edit:

$fillable is not the problem in this case as $guarded is set to an empty array which allows for all fields to be mass assignable through the create method. [Eloquent mass assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#allowing-mass-assignment)

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems in the code provided:

1. As commented by @sta, you should allow the `Model` attributes to be mass assignable by using the `$fillable` property in the `User` class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     *@var array
     */
     protected $fillable = [
         'name',
         'email', 
         'password',
     ];
    
    protected $guarded = [];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

2. As commented by @Remy, we should make sure to use the correct `class`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\User; // <-- corrected line

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $data = [
            'name' => 'elon',
            'email' => 'elon@gmail.com',
            'password' => 'password',
        ];

        User::create($data);

        $user = User::all();
        return $user;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this helpful for me in laravel 8, this worked fine in all versions because many times if we import class and it auto import another one so please check that you import this class or another one.

```
use App\Models\User;
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

in the `UserController.php` try to use

```
use App\Models\User;
```

Answer (score 0):

in laravel 7 this work for me :

```
use App\User;
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had to stop the server in terminal with `ctrl + c` and the restart the server with `php artisan serve` It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

by adding this in my model

> protected $guarded = [];

it save me from my misery thanks!

Comment: Please don't add _thanks_ as answers. They don't actually provide an answer to the question, and can be perceived as noise by its future visitors. Instead, [upvote answers](/help/privileges/vote-up) you like. This way future visitors of the question will see a higher vote count on that answer, and the answerer will also be rewarded with reputation points. See [Why is voting important](/help/why-vote).